# inserting an image on already done registration form

Tags: php, mysql

Im creating a directory registration system using PHP/MySQL which allows a user to insert an image/avatar. The user can register and everything goes to the database, my problem is regarding the image upload and retrieval.

signup.php

```
<table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="4">
```

Logo :

```
<td><div class="sm-textfeild-in">
  <div class="textfeild-in">
    <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload"  class="validate[required,ajax[ajaxUserCallPhp]]] textfeild-in-152"/>
  </div></div></td>
    <td align="left">
           </td>
    <td>Accepted Formats: <font color="red">jpg, jpeg, png, gif</font></div></td>
</tr>
```

Save.php

Function.php

```
 function getdirector()
{
    global $db;
    $sql = "SELECT user_id, profileName, firstname, surname FROM ".PREFIX."users Where admin_approve = '1' and email_verified='1' order by date_register desc limit 3";

    $data = $db->select($sql);
    $return = '';
    $return .= '<table width="340" border="0" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="2">';
    foreach($data as $d)
    {
    $return .= '<tr height="50">
                <td width="80" valign="top">
                    <img src="'.getUserImage($d['user_id'], 75).'" width="76" height="52" class="yash" />
```

Directory.php

```
<?php echo getdirectory(); ?>
```

I can pull everything, im struggling with getting the uploaded image

Comment: Could you show us all of the `<form>`, one quick check would be does it have the `enctype= "multipart/form-data "` attribute within the `<form>` tag. 

Can you also clarify which (or both) you are struggling with; uploading the image, or retrieving the uploaded image.

Comment: Please edit `function getdirectory()` code formatting. Note that the function name seems to be incorrect also.

Comment: `<form name="frm_signup" id="frm_signup" action="index.php?page=save" method="post">`

Comment: @Daniel Please explain your question briefly, nothing is clear what you have mentioned